# How to retrieve an item from Azure Cosmos DB using _rid or _self

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

```
var response = await container.ReadItemAsync<JsonUserAc>(emailId, new PartitionKey(emailId));
```

I am able to retrieve a document/item by its Id (emailid is id in my case) but i am unable to retrieve a document/item by it's _rid  or  _self .

Since _rid and _self are unique across a collection, I'm hoping there is a way to retrieve a document/item by either of these. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Could you describe why you need the _rid or _self? The id + partitionkey also unique across the collection so they serve as unique identifier of the document.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I want to implement a remember me feature for logins. For this i am generating GUID. On the user's browser in the cookies i am storing this GUID . Also storing the _rid to identify the user. It would be easier and cheaper (RUs are least while retrieving document by ID?) to store email id instead of _ridin the cookie. But i'm not sure if it's ok to store email ids in cookie.  So the 3 options for cookie are emailid (easiest for me) OR _rid OR encrypted email id (this one is hard for me but i think if i keep trying i might get it)

Comment: Since the document identity and uniqueness is the ID + PK, and based on your code, you are using the same value for both (I guess `/id` is your Partition Key definition), then simply storing the emailId value should suffice for uniqueness read. You don't need the _rid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document identity and uniqueness is represented by the ID + Partition Key value, you don't need the `_rid`.

Based on the comments and the code, it looks like your `id` is an email identifier and so is the Partition Key (maybe the Partition Key Definition is `/id`).

In the comments you mention you want to store this information in cookies. Since this information seems to be an email, it might be more secure to encrypt it.

But going to the original question: Just use the ID and Partition Key and that ensures uniqueness and identity of the document.